# Removing trailing whitespaces of a string in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove trailing whitespaces of a string in a concise/efficient way.

Let's say I have the string:

```
string input= "2 2 +                 "
```

I used this in an attempt to make it `input = "2 2+"`

```
  std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(input.begin(), input.end(), ' ');
  input.erase(end_pos, input.end());
  cout << input << endl;
```

However, it removed *all* the whitespaces.

How would I implement it so it only removes *trailing* whitespaces?

Comment: As @karim pointed out, there is already an answer there, another option if to just use `find_last_not_of` combined with `substr`.

Comment: "Extracting" implies that you want to keep the spaces, whereas in fact the opposite is true. We call this "trimming". If you'd searched for that, you'd have found the answer very quickly. :) So now you know.